# Tensorflow: can it run ResNet-101 on a GTX 1070 (8GB)?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

With tensorflow, is a GTX 1070 (8GB RAM) enough to run ResNet-101 ?

As per the ResNet paper, ResNet is "simpler" than VGG-16. Since VGG-16 already runs well in my current 4-GB GPU (GTX 960), a bigger 8GB 1070 GPU should have no problem with ResNet right?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this benchmark](https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks):

> We benchmark all models with a minibatch size of 16 and an image size of 224 x 224; this allows direct comparisons between models, and allows all but the ResNet-200 model to run on the GTX 1080, which has only 8GB of memory.

All ResNet models but the 200 layers deep one fit in the 8GB 1080 GTX. As the 1070 GTX has also 8GB of memory, the ResNets up to 152 layers will fit into the GPU's memory, but not the deeper ones.

Comment: Your link is based on torch implementation but not tensorflow.

Comment: Yes I know, but the model parameters use the same memory if they are represented all by 32 bit floats, and I don't think the framework memory overhead is large enough to make huge memory usage differences between torch and tensorflow. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: But does the mini-batch size of 16 not mean a decrease in accuracy?